Define the case status for retained cases after merge
I'm looking for the metadata where the status for cases is defined after a merge. Without this the test for our case merge are failing with this error msg:
Merge failed. First exception on row 0 with id 5007Y00000T9bneQAB; first error: MERGE_FAILED, We couldn't merge these cases. Check your case status settings and try again.: []
I have already enabled case merge and keeping the record in the definition file. But I can't find any trace of where the status is defined. Theoretically, one solution would be to not run this particular test during packaging, but that seems like a not-so-optimal solution.
Part of the scratch-def.json:
"caseSettings": {
    "caseMergeInLightning": true,
    "keepCaseMergeRecords": true
}



I vaguely remember doing this manually in the target org - but I'm an enterprise user, not an ISV. My tests were written to detect null/non-null in Case.MasterRecordTypeId as well as to detect the old record still present in soql

Yes, the problem in this case is that we can't do it manually in the org, since it's done during the packing process and in a pipeline test. And salesforce throws the error during the merge and not in our asserts.

right -- but instead of verifying that the merge status field is X, verify that the merge loser record still exists after merge and arguably, that its status has changed from previous value

As I said, the exception is thrown during the merge, there is no option to assert somethin afterwards. The merge itself fails, if the status is not set in the scratch org.
